# Array value with predifined mathematical operation

Tags: php, arrays, math

How can i print the result of a an array item with value `3378/100` by doing the mathematical operation just by getting the value? Is it possible or should i split the value with `/` delimiter first?

Thanks!

Comment: `3378/100` is a key of array or a value? Show your code, please

Comment: `$values = explode('/', $myData); $result = $values[0] / $values[1];` but where does this array value come from? Is it user input?

Comment: This is a value and i need to get the math result of it. But i don't know if i can get it by reading it or if i should split it first. I tried to print the value but it seems that it is considered as "string"..

Comment: Mark that did the job! No, it's predefined, hardcoded :)

Answer (score 1):

If value of array is string - you must to split it first with `explode()` function for example:

```
$values = explode('/', $array[$key]);
$result = $values[0] / $values[1];
```

To show type of array value use

```
var_dump($array[$key]);
```

But if value already contains an operation of `3378/100`, then print out them:

```
echo $array[$key];
```

Comment: With echo i get 3378/100 (string), i need to get the result of the operation stored in that arrary-item...

Comment: so you must to use `explode()`

Comment: Thank you! Worked with mark's and your assistance! Explode was needed!

Comment: You can also use [eval()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.eval.php), but it isn't good idea!